# Using the Netflix Odata service with WP71

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, odata

I'm trying to use the Netflix Odata service with WP71 but it aint working. What's wrong with this code?

private const string NETFLIX_CATALOG_URI = "http://odata.netflix.com/v2/Catalog/";

```
public ObservableCollection<Title> SearchByTitle(string searchKey)
    {
        NetflixCatalog catalog = new NetflixCatalog(new Uri(NETFLIX_CATALOG_URI));

        var query = catalog.Titles.Where(t => t.Name.Contains(searchKey));

        DataServiceCollection<Title> titles = new DataServiceCollection<Title>(catalog);
        titles.LoadAsync(query);
        return titles;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific than just "Not working"? How does it behave, and how do you expect it to behave. If you get an exception what is it and preferably post a callstack of it as well.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant by "not working" is that I'm not getting any results back. I get no exceptions.

Comment: Do you wait for the async operation to complete? Or hook up the data binding such that when it does the data gets propagated to the UI? I would try to register even handler on the completed event and see if it gets invoked and what is the content of the collection then.

Comment: I wanna use this class in my viewmodel and assign it to a property there. something like
    IRemoteDataStore dataStore = new NetflixRemoteDataStore();
            SearchResults = dataStore.SearchByTitle("Godfather"); and the bind in to the View

Comment: I understand the intent, but you're saying you don't get any data back, so I'm trying to help you figure out why. Could you please try to register the event handler and see if it gets called and what data you get there?

Comment: LOL sorry it turns out I was just being too impatient. I ran the application I went out to brew some coffee when I came back the movies was on the screen. Sorry to have wasted your time =/

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the HTTP request generated from your Linq, you will notice that the format is not supported by Netflix.  It will work if you change it to:

```
var query = catalog.Titles.Where(t => t.Name.StartsWith(searchKey));
```

But, of course, it is not exactly the search you want... and I am looking for the answer on that too.